# how to call table values inside pl/sql scripts?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I call inside the pl/sql script ?

```
SELECT d.device_id, 
       d.state_id, 
       ds.distributor 
INTO   a1, b1, c1 
FROM   device_t d, 
       device_smartcard_t ds 
WHERE  d.poid_id0 = ds.obj_id0 
       AND d.device_id = e1.device_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but if you want access to those values in a PL/SQL block you can do:

```
declare
  a1 device_t.device_id%type;
  b1 device_t.state_id%type;
  c1 device_smartcard_t.distributor%type;
begin
   select d.device_id, d.state_id, ds.distributor
   into   a1,          b1,         c1
   from   device_t d
   join   device_smartcard_t ds 
   on     d.poid_id0  = ds.obj_id0 
   and    d.device_id = E1.device_id; -- (What's E1?)

   -- Do what you like with a1, b1 and c1
end;
/
```

I have taken the liberty of changing your cross join into an inner join. Note that Oracle will throw an exception if your query returns multiple or no results; you can handle this using an `exception` clause, catching the `TOO_MANY_ROWS` and `NO_DATA_FOUND` exceptions.

Comment: cursor E1 is  select * from tmp_dileep ;

Comment: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: Like I say, `select into` only works when you're fetching one record. If you want to deal with multiple records, then you can fetch into a cursor or use `bulk collect into`... See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Comment: @user2160359 - to fix too many rows exception you need to use explicit cursor, if this is what you meant by calling table values. What do you need to do? To write PL/SQL program or some SQL script?

Comment: i want to write PL/SQL program . can u please send a sample program to fetch the data from  multiple tables. my data in  one table and i want  to fetch the data  from    two different  table ( having join)

Comment: SO is not here to write your code. If you're still having difficulties with how PL/SQL works, please post another question (perhaps link it back to this one, for others' reference) that is explicit, clear and detailed with regards to your requirements/problem. That covers things like what you are trying to achieve and, in this case, the schema you are working with and desired output. Importantly, people will be more willing to help you if you also demonstrate how you have tried to solve the problem yourself, including code you have already written and any errors it produces.